# Failure querying the global catalog using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

## Scenario

- Domain `root.local` which contains a universal scope group `rootgroup` (i.e. `ROOT\rootgroup`)
- Domain `child.root.local` which contains a user `childuser` (i.e. `CHILD\childuser`) who is a member of `ROOT\rootgroup`.
- I'm using a `PrincipalContext` constructed with the child domain and want to be able to resolve `ROOT\rootgroup` based off of its SID.

## Implementation

I ran a quick sanity test using Get-ADGroup in PowerShell to verify that passing the global catalog port would seem to get the correct results

```
$> Get-ADGroup –Server child.root.local -Filter 'sid -eq $groupSid'
$> # No result
$> Get-ADGroup –Server child.root.local:3268 -Filter 'sid -eq $groupSid'
DistinguishedName : CN=rootgroup,CN=Users,DC=root,DC=local
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Universal
Name              : rootgroup
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : 0c65063f-4ba9-4469-a3a5-142f6f8efaf5
SamAccountName    : rootgroup
SID               : S-1-5-21-2643412326-2562497744-373403-4104
$>
```

Everything seemed fine so I implemented it in my C# project using a `PrincipalContext` constructed using the domain and port but when I go to test the code and it fails.  To simplify things and weed out errors like permissions of the executing user I prototyped the pertinent logic in PowerShell.

```
dsam = "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" 
$rtn = [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($dsam)

$domain = "child.root.local:3268"
$context = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext( `
               [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, `
               $domain)

$user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity( `
            $context, `
            [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName, `
            "child\childuser") 

$obj = $user.GetUnderlyingObject() -as [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]
$obj.RefreshCache(@("tokenGroups"))

$groups = $obj.Properties["tokenGroups"]
for ($i=0; $i -lt $groups.Count; $i++)
{
    $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($groups[$i],0)
    $group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity( `
                 $context, `
                 [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::Sid, `
                 $sid.Value)

    Write-Host ("Group: '{0}'; Sid: '{1}" -f $group,$sid.Value) 
}
```

I tried various domain strings when constructing the `PrincipalContext`

- `child.root.local:3268`
- `child:3268`
- `DCServer.child.root.local:3268`

None of them seem allow me to fetch a result for the group in the root domain.

```
...
Group: ''; Sid: 'S-1-5-21-2643412326-2562497744-373403-4104
...
```

I've verified that using the `DirectorySearcher` to perform a global catalog query also successfully finds the group

```
$ds = "System.DirectoryServices"
$rtn = [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($ds)

$entry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://$forest")
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($entry)

for ($i=0; $i -lt $groups.Count; $i++)
{
    $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($groups[$i],0)
    $searcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectSid=$($sid.Value)))"
    $res = $searcher.FindOne()
    $res.Properties.samaccountname
}
```